# Logical-based row selection using evaluated statements not evaluating correctly in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

[My Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK00j.png)

I have the above dataframe and want to get all rows where Team = ATL
I've written the following code:

[Code I've written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgYcD.png)

But get the following:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Team, Matchup, Date]
Index: []

Comment: the value in the column "team" might not be 'ATL'. Go check if it has hanging blank(s)

Comment: Please post your sample data and sample code in text format for us to try it out.

Comment: or use `df = pd.read_csv('team 2018-2019,csv', delim_whitespace=True)` .   delim_whitespace : Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '    ') will be used as the sep. Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'. If this option is set to True, nothing should be passed in for the delimiter parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The values in the column "team" had hanging blanks, or trailing whitespace.  I went into the original csv file and did a "replace all" spaces with no space and that fixed the issue.